# List the elements of the set $\{X \in \mathbb Z \mid 4X^2 +11X = 0\}$

Tags: quadratics

I don't get this maths equation

Can anybody explain it ?
Thanks

> List the elements of the following set:
>   $A=\{X \in \mathbb Z \mid 4X^2 +11X = 0\}$.

Comment: If I read symbols correctly, it asks to find the integer roots of $4x^2+11x = (4x+11)x$...

Comment: @Milly Not exactly, since the roots should be relative integers.

Comment: By "integer" I meant $\mathbb{Z}$, not $\mathbb{N}$ (natural numbers).

Answer (score 4):

This means that $A$ is the set of all integers $x$ for which $4x^2 + 11x = 0$.

When you solve the equation $4x^2 + 11x = 0$ you will find that only $x = 0$ and $x = -\frac{11}{4}$ satisfy it. Since you're only looking for $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, you can conclude that $A = \{0\}$.